# How to disable keys in MySQL InnoDB tables?

Tags: mysql, database, innodb, optimization

Is it possible to disable keys in InnoDB tables?

If yes, how?

If not, why?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I was under the impression InnoDB can have keys disabled and enabled. I just did some digging. It cannot be done. So, I was wrong.

Key constraints, however, can be turned on and off for a specific session:

- If you have UNIQUE secondary indexes,
  you can try setting this to speed up
  INSERTs that are disk bound:
  `SET unique_checks = 0;`
- To disable foreign key checks for a
  suggestion, use Randy Melder's suggestion:
  `SET foreign_key_checks = 0;`

Comment: As for the "why", see http://stackoverflow.com/a/9525780/632951