# CHECK TABLE locking a large (12GB) InnoDB table on MySQL

Tags: mysql, innodb

I'm having problems with a large MySQL InnoDB table and I was wondering if anyone here had advice for improving stabililty.

The issue that I'm having is that `CHECK TABLE ... FAST` will lock the table, preventing any reading, and for a table this large, that means its offline for an hour.

The default Debian install will run `CHECK TABLE` on everything whenever MySQL starts, and this is causing downtime.  For now, I have disabled this functionality, but it makes me a little nervous to me mucking with these kind of system settings.

I have another cronjob that was bulk loading data into the table that was using `ALTER TABLE ... DISABLE KEYS` and `ALTER TABLE ... ENABLE KEYS`, and it's possible that this is related, but I haven't been able to confirm that yet.

Has anyone seen situations where `CHECK TABLE` prevents access to large InnoDB tables?

Answer (score 1):

[I wrote in ServerFault awhile back](https://serverfault.com/questions/234893/how-to-disable-keys-in-mysql-innodb) to show that you cannot DISABLE KEYS and ENABLE KEYS on an InnoDB table.

CHECK TABLE should always table lock any table MyISAM or InnoDB.

You could create a script called /var/lib/mysql/my_init.sql with the following

**CHECK TABLE < whatever table 1 >;
CHECK TABLE < whatever table 2 >;
...**

This file should contain whever number of tables you want to CHECK TABLE on.

Now add this line to /etc/my.cnf

**init_file=/var/lib/mysql/my_init.sql**

Then restart mysql and the custom check table script will run.

BTW I hope you are using innodb_file_per_table. If you are not, [please read this URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927690/howto-clean-a-mysql-innodb-storage-engine/4056261#4056261)

Comment: Yeah, the fact that `CHECK TABLE` locks is my problem!  If it locks, why is Debian configured by default to call it whenever MySQL starts?  The whole house of cards seems very shaky to me.